# Am I rooted or not?

Tags: android, root

I am trying to figure out if my Android device is rooted or not. The Superuser app is no where to be found. In a terminal emulator on my phone, I can't type the command `su`, and the command `id` reports that I'm not root. However, when I use the `adb shell`, I have full root access to the phone, which is confusing to me. Does this mean I'm rooted, or not?

Comment: What command did you execute on the adb shell that makes you think you are root?

Comment: does it show # or $ in the adb shell prompt

Comment: You might be judging if you have root from your ability to cd to system directories and /
whoever if you try to ls in any restricted ones, you'll likely find that you are denied permission

Comment: @Robert I executed the `id` command which gave me `uid=0(root) gid=0(root)`, and I can execute the `su` command without it complaining.

Comment: @nandeesh It shows a # in the adb shell prompt, but a $ in the terminal emulator.

Comment: @nandeesh , i am getting # prompt !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the build you are using is either debug or userdebug.

In this case apps cannot get root access since su is not present. Only ADB_SHELL will get root access.

You can push precompiled su to /system/bin after executing a adb remount

Edit: If you want root access from apps then follow this [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=449536)

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. I don't necessarily want to gain root access, though. I only want to be able to say whether or not I am rooted.

Comment: Thanks! So would you say the best way to check if the phone is rooted is to execute the `id` command in a terminal emulator? Or the `su` command perhaps?

Comment: its quite difficult to know, because if someone wants to hide existence of su they can just rename su to something else and use the command to get root access. id command will only give the current user id, so i dont think its useful